# printf() function with some "relationship" with my pointers struct in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, stack, printf

i was studying the C language and this power in memory management,(in this case i was studying the creation of Stack data structure in C), but when i was refactoring my code (deleting the useless printf's function for pointing me the algorithm at work), i deleted a printf function in this code bellow that i point it, and when i re-run my code, de values that has in the stack struct has changed, here the code (some name are in pt_br, so i'm going to translate to help the code understanding):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
  int *arr;
  size_t size;
  unsigned int index;
}Pilha;

Pilha* criar_pilha(size_t size){ //"criar_pilha" = create_stack
  int array[size];
  Pilha* pilha_f =  malloc(sizeof(Pilha)); //"pilha_f" = stack_f
  pilha_f->size = size;
  pilha_f->arr = array;
  pilha_f->index = 0;
  return pilha_f;
}

void push_pilha(Pilha* pilha_f,int valor){ //"valor" = value
  if (!(pilha_f->size-1< pilha_f->index)) {
    pilha_f->arr[pilha_f->index] = valor;
    pilha_f->index++;
  }

}
int pop_pilha(Pilha* pilha_f){
  int valor;
  if ( (pilha_f->index-1) < 0) {
    return NULL;
  }else{
    pilha_f->index= pilha_f->index-1;
    //printf("%d",pilha_f->index);
    valor = pilha_f->arr[pilha_f->index]; 
  }
  return valor;
}

int main(){
  Pilha* nova_pilha = criar_pilha(3);// "nova_pilha" = new_stack
  int temp;
  printf("pilha criada com sucssso");// THIS FUNCTION THAT MAKES THE ERROR WHEN DELETED
  push_pilha(nova_pilha,4);
  push_pilha(nova_pilha,5);
  push_pilha(nova_pilha,72);

  temp = pop_pilha(nova_pilha);
  printf("\n%d",temp);
  temp = pop_pilha(nova_pilha);
  printf("\n%d",temp);
  temp = pop_pilha(nova_pilha);
  printf("\n%d",temp);

  free(nova_pilha);
  return 0;
}
```

the output:

```
pilha criada com sucesso

72
5
4
```

OBS: the reason of i created the "tmp" is because when i trying to print directly using "prinf("%d",pop_pilha(nova_pilha)); the code throws an "segmentation fault"- so if u can explain why this happens i will be very gratefully

OBS2: the error that hapens in above has the some variations when i change the content in printf function adding the keywords like "\n", but if i change the content string the problem dont hapens, unless if i delete the entire line

output after deletion the line:

```
pilha criada com sucesso

72
0
0
```

i don't know if this can help, but im using the Archcraft (Linux) with gcc 13.2.1

Comment: ALWAYS enable your compiler's warnings. With gcc, I use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. This produces two warnings you should start by fixing. 1) `<source>:28:27: warning: comparison of unsigned expression in '< 0' is always false [-Wtype-limits]` 2) `<source>:29:12: warning: returning 'void *' from a function with return type 'int' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]`

Comment: In the function `criar_pilha` you allocate your `array` on the stack. The stack gets freed after the function is done so `array` will be destroyed. However you are still using it through the pointer `pilha_f->arr` which is UB.

Comment: Getting different results when you add or remove an irrelevant `printf()` is a common symptom of a program with bugs that cause undefined behavior.

Comment: @joel , thanks, this fix the issue, i dont know why the printf() create this strange relationship, but u reminded me of the local scope that any function has, when i transform the array in the global array using malloc(), the problem has disapeared, but i have one more question, array by malloc() is in struct, when i free the struct i free the arr that are in struct too ? or do i need to free it too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake in your program is in your `criar_pilha()` function. You create a VLA (variable length array) which is allocated on the stack. Then you make the `pilha_f->arr` point to this `array` and return `pilha_f`, but once the function returns, its local memory on the stack gets automatically freed again and `pilha_f->arr` is pointing to an invalid address. If you dereference that pointer you have UB (undefined behavior), which means that anything can happen. If you are lucky, your program still works. But it can just crash or behave differently than you might expect. Therefore you should never ever rely on UB.

To fix this you can allocate memory for `pilha_f->arr` via `malloc()`, just like you did with `pilha_f` itself. Your function `criar_pilha()` could then look like this:

```
Pilha* criar_pilha(size_t size) {
    // same as "sizeof(Phila)", but this way you only write the type once
    // when you use a variable instead of a type with sizeof(), you can drop the parentheses
    Pilha* pilha_f = malloc(sizeof *pilha_f);
    // remember that malloc() can return NULL on failure and dereferening it would be UB
    if (!pilha_f) {     // same as "if (pilha_f == NULL)"
        return NULL;
    }

    pilha_f->arr = malloc(sizeof *(pilha_f->arr) * size);
    // if the array could not be allocated, free the struct and return NULL
    if (!pilha_f->arr) {
        free(pilha_f);
        return NULL;
    }

    pilha_f->size = size;
    pilha_f->index = 0;

    return pilha_f;
}
```

Since you allocated both the struct and its array separately on the heap, you need to free them both as well to not leak any memory. Remember to free them in reverse order. You first allocated the struct, then its member. When deallocating you first deallocate the member, then the struct because if you freed the struct first, accessing its member would be UB. To make it easier for a user you should write a function that does this:

```
void free_pilha(Pilha* pilha) {
    free(pilha->arr);
    free(pilha);
}
```

---

There are a few other things I'd like to point out.

While VLAs can be convenient to use they should be used with caution, since they can lead to stack overflow if you allocate a to large array, or use them in deeply recursive functions. In your case (even if you could use the function local VLA) you should definitely use the heap to store your array.

In `pop_pilha()` you `return NULL;` in one path. In my implementation of the standard library it is `#define`d to `((void *)0)`. So you are returning a pointer in a function that returns an `int`. Just return `0` or some other value like `INT_MIN` to signal that your `Pilha` is empty. Further the condition `if ((pilha_f->index - 1) < 0)` is ill formed. `index` is of the unsigned type `size_t`, which means that it can never be less than `0`. Subtracting `1` from it can result in underflow and does not change its sign. You could instead write `if (pilha_f->index < 1)`. You have a similar problem in `push_pilha()`.

To be honest I can't exactly tell you why the call to `printf()` was changing the behavior of your program, but I once heard that the first `printf()` call internally allocates some memory and that this could hide some memory related UB. But don't quote me on this.

Comment: thx, i fixed the issues that u point to me, creating a malloc to arr, freeit and fixing the If statement in the Memory, thanks so much,i'm a begginer in C programing so thx to take your time to explain me :)